# Change one single image in div of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, setinterval

I am trying to change an image scr of one random image in a div with images. This is my code :

```
setInterval(ChangeToBomb, 3000);

function ChangeToBomb() {

    $('#depionnen img').fadeOut(100, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', bombs[0]).fadeIn(100);
    })
}
```

At this moment every image in the `div` element is changing.

Does anyone know how to do this for a single random image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a random number from 0 to length-1 of images. use this variable to target the random image by index:

```
  var randomimgindex= (Math.random() * $('#depionnen img').length);
  $('#depionnen img:eq('+randomimgindex+')').fadeOut(100, function(){
    $(this).attr('src', bombs[0]).fadeIn(100);
  });
```

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a number in the range [0, 1). As written, the last element will never be picked.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: thanks. should be good after setting the max to actual length of image elements.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a variation of Milind's solution. Rather than build a selector just to pull up an image, since we already *have* the list of images, just grab one of them from the list:

```
var images = $('#depionnen img');
var randomimgindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

$(images[randomimgindex]).fadeOut(100, function(){
  $(images[randomimgindex]).attr('src', bombs[0]).fadeIn(100);
});
```

```js
var bombs = [ "http://placehold.it/300x300" ];

var images = $('#depionnen img');
var randomimgindex= Math.floor(Math.random() * (images.length));

$(images[randomimgindex]).fadeOut(100, function(){
  $(images[randomimgindex]).attr('src', bombs[0]).fadeIn(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="depionnen">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a number in the range [0, 1). As written, the last element will never be picked.

Comment: Yep. Copied that blindly. Fixed and simplified now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector

```
$('#depionnen img:nth-child(' + randomlyGeneratedNumber + ')').fadeOut(100, function(){
    $(this).attr('src', bombs[0]).fadeIn(100);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number between 0 and the last index of the image, and use it to pick an image randomly.

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * bombs.length);

$('#depionnen img').fadeOut(100, function(){
    $(this).attr('src', bombs[randomNumber]).fadeIn(100);
})
```